# $\mathbb P^0_A$ as a projective scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is $\mathbb P^0_A$ =ProjA[x] isomorphic to SpecA? How can I show the homogeneous prime ideal of A[x] is just prime ideal of A? I know this is a silly question, but I am totally new to projective thing. Thanks!

Comment: Homegenous elements of a polynomial ring in one variable look very easy. You can easily classify all homgenous ideals of $A[x]$ (assuming you know all ideals of $A$). Then you can easily see which of these are prime and which do not contain the irrelevant ideal. You will see that you are precisely left with the prime ideals of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trace back to the definition of the scheme structure on $\mathrm{Proj}$.

As a scheme, by definition we have $\mathrm{Proj} A[x]=D_{+}(x)=\mathrm{Spec}A[x]_{(x)}$, which is $\mathrm{Spec} A$ because $A[x]_{(x)}=A$.